# " If null" operator: "??" in Dart seems not to work with conditional member access "?."

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen the following construct several times in Flutter code:

```
var t;
var s = t?.round().toString() ?? '0.0';
```

but it seems there is something amiss. I get a 'null' instead of '0.0':

```
main() {
  var t;
  var s = t?.round().toString() ?? '0.0';
  print(s); // It prints "null" instead of "0.0". Why is that?
  
  var a;
  var b = a ?? 'a is null';
  print(b); // It prints "a is null", as expected
  
  var x = 'x is not null';
  var y = x ?? "Any";
  print(y); // It prints "x is not null", as expected
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're calling `toString` on `null`.

The result of `t?.round()` will be `null` as expected. Then `toString` is called on `null`, which returns the string `"null"`, which is a non-null value. Therefore the value provided by the right side of the `??` operator is never used. If you want to use that right side value you need to add another null access operator in the chain. So do

```dart
var s = t?.round()?.toString() ?? '0.0';
```

The result of `t?.round()` will still be `null` as expected. Then calling `toString` with the null access operator will return `null` again instead of the non-null string `"null"`. Then the `null` value is actually seen by the `??` operator and the value of `'0.0'` is provided.

---

```dart
main() {
  var t;
  var s = t?.round()?.toString() ?? '0.0';
  print(s); // It prints "0.0"
  
  var a;
  var b = a ?? 'a is null';
  print(b); // It prints "a is null", as expected
  
  var x = 'x is not null';
  var y = x ?? "Any";
  print(y); // It prints "x is not null", as expected
}
```